# PowerPoint automation c++ change textsize

Tags: c++, office-automation, powerpoint-2007

I am working on adding a chart to a powerpoint 2007 slide in c++ and everything is adding but I cannot find out how to change the `font` `size`.  If anyone knows how to do this for powerpoint 2007 or know where to find a solution, that would be great thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your table is a shape.  The shape has a .Table method that returns a Table object.

To set the text size, use something like this (in VB/VBA-speak):

```
With oTbl  ' a reference to the table object
  For x = 1 to .Rows.Count
    For y = 1 to .Columns.count
      With .Cell(x,y).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Font.Size = 8  ' or whatever you want
      End with
    Next
  Next
End With
```

If the table cell's height/width aren't large enough to accommodate the newly sized text, the text won't change size.  Annoying.